# jqGrid different summaries on different group levels

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I want to create different summaries on different group levels in an jqGrid, like this:

[image: custom summeries jqGrid]
*Image is based on this demo: http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/grouping/multiple_columns/index.html*

On the top level group I would like jqGrid to calculate an average and on the lower level groups it would calculate a sum.

Is this possible in jqGrid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem which I see: you need to use **different** `summaryType` (`"sum"` and `"avg"`) on different levels of the grid. There are no simple way to implement this. I think it's possible, but the code will be not simple. The code can depends on version of jqGrid, which you use and from the fork ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) of some old version <=4.7).

To place result in header is easy you need just add `groupSummaryPos: ["header", "header"]` property in `groupingView`. You should set either `summaryType: "sum"` or `summaryType: "avg"` in the column `Freight`.

**UPDATE**: I implemented new feature in free jqGrid. Now one can use `summaryType` and `summaryTpl` defined as arrays. [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/grouping2-summaryTypeAsArray.htm) have Total column defined as

```
{ name: "total", width: 75, template: "number",
    summaryTpl: [
        "<span style='color: red'>Avg: {0}</span>",
        "<span style='color: DarkRed'>Sum: {0}</span>"
    ],
    summaryType: ["avg", "sum"] },
```

The results of the demo looks like on the picture:

[image]

I have to remark, that the changes are not included in free jqGrid 4.10.0, which I published today, so you have to use the sources from GitHub to be able to use the feature.

Comment: I agree with your analysis. Do you have any pointers on how to solve the different summaryType difficulty?

Comment: @pacw: I extended the code of jqGrid in the fork which I develop: in [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid). Now one can easy to implement the requirements. See **UPDATED** part of my answer.

Comment: Nice! 

I see that the average is calculated on the rows on the  "lowest" level and not on the sum of the rows on the "middle" layers, eg. test 1 average is not the average of the sums of the 0.00 and 20.00 rows but the average of all the test1 rows. 

How would I calculate the average of the 0.00 and 20.00 rows?

Comment: @pacw: I think that you don't full correct. What exist on the "middle" layers? There are no items an the layer which can be used in the aggregation. At least "average" which you calculate in the way is **not average, but your custom aggregation function**. You can define `summaryType` as function with 4 parameters which should return new value based on the previous value (see [the line](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/js/grid.grouping.js#L94) of code where the function will be called and examine in debugger all parameters)

Comment: @pacw: Just think about the user who look at the grid where all groups are collapsed. One will see "test1" - avg: x , next row "test2" - avg: y. It means the average over all "test1" *items* and not some subgroups. I don't understand what information you need to display. You need include *clear description of the data, which you want to display*. Only having the clear test case I can decide whether you have some specific problem or it's common problem which could have other users. Only in the last case I could change the code of jqGrid once more to make the case easy to use.