# Jqgrid : Multi Level Group Summary

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqgrid with 3 levels of grouping as shown in the image.
I need to add summary for each groups on `account` column as in the image. 
[image: jqgrid]

**ColModel**

```
colModel:[
    {name:'typeId',         jsonmap : 'cell.typeId',            width:'100',    hidden:true},
    {name:'typeName',       jsonmap : 'cell.typeName',          width:'100',    hidden:true,    summaryType:nameSummary},
    {name:'classId',        jsonmap : 'cell.classId',           width:'100',    hidden:true},
    {name:'className',      jsonmap : 'cell.className',         width:'100',    hidden:true,    summaryType:nameSummary},
    {name:'groupId',        jsonmap : 'cell.groupId',           width:'100',    hidden:true},
    {name:'groupName',      jsonmap : 'cell.groupName',         width:'150',    hidden:true,    summaryType:nameSummary},
    {name:'accountCode',    jsonmap : 'cell.accountCode',       width:'75'},
    {name:'accountName',    jsonmap : 'cell.accountName',       width:'460'},
    {name:'openingBalance', jsonmap : 'cell.openingBalance',    width:'110',    align:"right",  formatter:amountFormatter,  summaryType:'sum'},
    {name:'debitTotal',     jsonmap : 'cell.debitTotal',        width:'110',    align:"right",  formatter:amountFormatter,  summaryType:'sum'},
    {name:'creditTotal',    jsonmap : 'cell.creditTotal',       width:'110',    align:"right",  formatter:amountFormatter,  summaryType:'sum'},
    {name:'closingBalance', jsonmap : 'cell.closingBalance',    width:'110',    align:"right",  formatter:numberFormatter,  summaryType:'sum'}      
],
```

**Grouping Options**

```
grouping: true,
groupingView : { 
    groupField : ['typeId','classId','groupId'], 
    groupText : ['<div style="background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #307ECC; color:white; font-size : 16px;" class="ui-jqgrid-titlebar ui-widget-header"><b> {typeName} </b></div>',
                 '<div style="background-color: #E0ECF8; font-size : 14px;" class="">{className}</div>',
                 '<div style="font-size : 13px;"><b> {groupName} </b></div>'], 
    groupCollapse : false, 
    groupOrder: ['asc','asc','asc'], 
    groupColumnShow: [false,false,false],
    groupSummary : [true, true, true]
},
```

How can I achieve this ?
I am using jQuery jqGrid v4.5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some time before I posted [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33394743/315935). The old jqGrid 4.5.2 have no possibilits to set *different* `summaryTpl` in `accountName` for both grouping levels. I implemented the feature in the latest version of **free jqGrid** which you can find on [GitHub](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid).

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/grouping2-summaryTypeAsArray1.htm) uses

```
summaryTpl: [
    "<span style='color: red'>Total name:</span>",
    "<span style='color: DarkRed'>Total date:</span>"
],
summaryType: ["count", "count"]
```

and displays the results like on the picture below:

[image]